# Как адаптировать верхнее меню для все видов телефона в vk mini apps на bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, vk-mini-apps

Пробую сделать приложение на bootstrap для vk mini apps
Шапка стандартная с bootstrap

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-vk">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <button class="btn nav-link">Екатеринбург</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

На компьютере все отлично отображается, проблема встала в мобильных версиях
Вот пример:

Samsung Galaxy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Iphone 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если на самсунге более менее, то на айфоне из-за челки все ломается

Как с этим бороться?

зы. Знаю про существование библиотеки VK UI для react, но react для меня темный лес и сейчас нет времени и желания на изучение react ради приложения для vk

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто если используете react

```
import { Platform} from 'react-native'
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      //do something...
    }
```

Или, если вам нужна дополнительная информация об устройстве:
Вы можете использовать Just use `NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo`

Есть много переменных, которые наверняка помогут вам:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'

console.log("NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo", NativeModules.RNDeviceInfo)
```

Вывод:
[image: Вывод:]

и уже по переменным загружать свое меню для определенного телефона

Comment: Спасибо, можно без использование react? На html css?

Answer (score 0):

по идее можно через php

```
if(preg_match('/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iem  obile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link  )|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar  (ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|b  umb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a  |jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|d  o|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran  |owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(4  0|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98  )|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))){ 
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'site.ru'){ 
            header('Location: http://wap.site.ru'); 
            die(); 
        } 
}
```

можно через js

```
<script>
    function DetectIphone()
    {
       var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
       if (uagent.search("iphone") > -1)
          alert('true');
       else
          alert('false');
    }
</script>
```